# Error Regarding User Defined Conversion

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have the following operator in my Visual WebPart's codebehind file:

```
public static implicit operator TemplateControl
(ScholarChip.PaymentProcessor.PaymentProcessor.PaymentProcessor target)
    {
        return ((target == null) ? null : target.TemplateControl);
    }
```

I'm receiving the error:

```
User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type
```

I'm unfamiliar with the above error.  Can anyone suggest how I might rectify it?  The code is being used in a Sharepoint 2010 Visual WebPart.

Thanks much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining a conversion between `PaymentProcessor` and `TemplateControl`, but you're not defining that conversion in either the `PaymentProcessor` class or the `TemplateControl` class.  TemplateClass seems like it's part of a framework, so I doubt you can define the conversion in that class.

A user-defined conversion must be a member of one of the two types being converted (which is just another way of saying what the error message says).  In other words, if you control the PaymentProcessor class, move the conversion into that class.  If you control neither class, you're out of luck, and you need to handle the conversion in a normal method.

As an example, this will give the same compiler error you saw:

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C
{
    public static implicit operator A(B source) { return new A(); }
}
```

This will compile:

```
class A {}
class B
{
    public static implicit operator A(B source) { return new A(); }
}
```

So will this:

```
class A
{
    public static implicit operator A(B source) { return new A(); }
}
class B {}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  It looks like TemplateControl is part of System.Web.UI.  Does this make any difference in how to handle above error?

Comment: @SidC sorry, for some reason, I missed this comment earlier.  The fact that TemplateControl is a framework class means that you have to define the conversion from `PaymentProcessor` to `TemplateControl` in the `PaymentProcessor` class, because it has to be either there or in the `TemplateControl` class, but you can't modify the `TemplateControl` class.  If you can't modify `PaymentProcessor` either, you could write an extension method to handle the null check.